# Can I use openssl to generate key/cert for tomcat?

Tags: ssl, tomcat, keytool

According to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Create_a_local_Certificate_Signing_Request_(CSR) I can use `keytool` to generate the key and cert for tomcat but can I use `openssl`?

If yes, is there any openssl guideline for tomcat?

Respond to: Mr Valerio Minetti

Yes, the goal is we want to setup the SSL on a tomcat server.
One of my colleagues created the CSR and sent to Thawte, and Thawte return us cert file.
Because my colleague is busy, he hand over this job to me, to setup the tomcat.
After investigating (not the openssl), the fact is my colleague created the CSR by Symantec SSL assistance.

Symantec generated 2 files:

```
www_xxxxxxxxxx_com_rsa_csr.txt
www_xxxxxxxxxx_com_rsa_private.key
```

My colleague use `www_xxxxxxxxxx_com_rsa_csr.txt` to apply cert from Thawte.

So now I need to  do the following steps?

1. using the keytool to create keystore
2. then import the private key `www_xxxxxxxxxx_com_rsa_private.key`
3. import the chain cert from Thawte
4. import our site cert

Am I correct?

Comment: Since you already have the private key and certificate now, [try this to import them into a Keystore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224863/1207760).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate certs and keys with openssl, but in order to have tomcat using them you will have to use keytool to import it in a tomcat keystore.

you can find some examples here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652916/converting-a-java-keystore-into-pem-format)

Comment: Oh thanks, I add more details by edit my question.

Comment: That's fine, u have to import signed cert, private key and chain cert into your keystore, and then tell tomcat where your keystore is.